# Как расширить класс Form1 двумя классами в c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, классы

Как расширить класс, который создается по умолчанию в visual studio двумя другими классами?

По умолчанию создается класс Form1, который расширен классом Form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

А мне нужно его расширить еще одним классом (Helper) вот так

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, Helper {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Пробовал читать про интерфейсы, но не смог их применить. Покажите, пожалуйста, на примере, конкретно вот с такой ситуацией Form1 : Form.

Класс Helper имеет всего один метод

```
string GetText() {
    return("1");
}
```

Comment: В C# можно наследовать только один класс и множество интерфейсов. Так что объявите класс GetText как интерфейс.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

То, что вы называете словом «расширить», обычно называется «произвести от»: класс `Form1` произведён от класса `Form`.

В C# нету множественного наследования. Но вы можете применить обходные пути.

1. «Выпрямить» иерархию наследования. Произвести класс `Helper` от `Form`, а `Form1` — от `Helper`.

   ```
   public class Helper : Form
   {
       public string GetText() { return "1"; }
   }

   public class Form1 : Helper
   {
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Вы можете воспользоваться extension-методами для «нелинейного» наследования.

   ```
   public interface IHelper
   {
   }

   public static class HelperImplementation
   {
       public static string GetText(this IHelper self)
       {
           return "1";
       }
   }

   public class Form1 : Form, IHelper
   {
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Быстрый и хороший ответ.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Дописал ещё про extension-методы